# How to validiate form onsubmit when form is submitted via a link instead of a button

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I've got the following simple test to validate the input on the form when it is submitted by clicking the "submit" link. Unfortunately, it doesn't validate the form.

```
<form id="testform" action = "?blah" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
  <input type="text" name="testinput" >
  <a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('testform').submit();">Submit</a>
</form>

<script>
function validateForm() {
    var x = document.forms["testform"]["testinput"].value;
    if (x == null || x == "") {
        alert("Field must be filled out");
        return false;
    }
}
</script>
```

If I replace submitting with a button instead of a link then it validates the form properly. But how can I ensure it validates when I am using a link to submit as in the above example?

Comment: A side note: x will never be null

Comment: Inline event registration (registering the event handlers in html) is a bad practice btw: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_tradmod.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating a function that triggers the validation when clicking on the link.

Example:

```
<form id="testform" action = "?blah" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
  <input type="text" name="testinput" >
  <a href="#" onclick="return false; submitForm()">Submit</a>
</form>

<script>
function validateForm() {
    var x = document.forms["testform"]["testinput"].value;
    if (x == null || x == "") {
        alert("Field must be filled out");
        return false;
    }
}
function submitForm() {
    if (validateForm()) {
        document.getElementById('testform').submit();
    }
}
</script>
```

**Note:** I would highly recommend decoupling your JavaScript from your HTML, but that's outside the scope of your question.

Comment: Shouldn't he prevent the default action of an `a` link as well by calling `e.preventDefault()` first?

Comment: @RobinHellemans Not in this case since the anchor is not a "submit" trigger - had the OP used a submit button, I would have forced a return false on click and then called the function.

Comment: Also, it's better to put document.getElementById('testform') outside of the submit form action, you don't want to retrieve the node every time you submit the code

Comment: but the default action of an a link is to go the href, no?

Comment: You got it - added the return false :)

Answer (score 1):

This works for me. It takes advantage of a variable and of an assigned method to *testform*:

```
<form id="testform" action = "?blah" onsubmit="return formValid">
  <input type="text" name="testinput" >
  <a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('testform').onsubmit();">Submit</a>
</form>

<script>

var formValid = false;

document.getElementById('testform').onsubmit = function(){
    console.log('submit');
    formValid = validateForm();
};

function validateForm() {
    var x = document.forms["testform"]["testinput"].value;
    if (x == null || x == "") {
        alert("Field must be filled out");
        return false;
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here comes a jQuery style way of doing it.

```
<form id="testform" action = "?blah" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
    <input type="text" name="testinput" />
  <a href="#" onclick="$('form').submit();">Submit</a>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
function validateForm() {
    if ($.trim($("[name=testinput]").val()) == "") {
        alert("Field must be filled out");
        return false;
    }
}
</script>
```